# Is there any danger in changing the labels of my hard drives?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, dual-boot, fstab

I've have both Ubuntu and Arch installed on my computer, and want to change the labels of the `/` and `/home` partitions (four in total), to make it clear which is which. Can this potentially break anything?

The only thing that I can think of is `/etc/fstab`; this shouldn't be an issue in my case, since it defines partitions by UUID, not label.

Comment: Take a look at your grub.conf for UUIDs.

Comment: @Cyrus I don't have a file called `grub.conf` on either install, but I'm not sure if I was unclear. I mean to say that in my `/etc/fstab`, I've already defined partitions based on UUID, and not labels, so I don't envisage changing the labels to be a problem for this file.

Comment: grub.conf and menu.lst, if they're installed, will be under /boot.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Grub is installed through my Ubuntu system. I can see a file now (slightly different to the comment) at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. No `menu.lst` though. FWIW `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` contains numerous references to UUIDs. One of my partitions is called "root"; I can see numerous references to "root", but I think at least some are to a literal root, not to my label.

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered. Yes, grub.cfg would be under /boot, grub.conf (if present) would be in /etc.

Comment: The only place that labels are used is in the auto-mounting of removable drives.  If you name a USB stick's partition or filesystem then this is the name you should see on a modern distro's file browser and it will also be the name of the mount point.  Everything else (grub, fstab etc) uses UUID or PARTUUID.  I've just done what you're proposing and had no issues.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thanks for the anecdotal evidence. I just did the same and had no issues either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard drives usually don't have labels, it's filesystems that do. Here are the main places where a filesystem label is likely to come up:

- In `/etc/fstab`.
- In your bootloader configuration (e.g. `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`). If your Grub configuration is automatically generated, run `update-grub` after changing your labels and verify that the result is what you wanted.
- Mostly for removable devices: in the configuration of automounting tools (in custom udev rules, as directory name under `/media` or `/run/media/user_name` (if not created on the fly), in `/etc/pmount.*`, in `/etc/auto.misc` and files referenced from `/etc/auto.master`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, labels aren't that much used in the unix world, so there isn't any danger in changing them. Keep using the UUIDs and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll leave the question open for a few days to see what other responses I get, since it's hard to definitively say there is *no* danger, because we don't know of a specific example that counters this. (I mean that is a fault of the question, not your response.)